# Change tintcolor of navigationbar PKAddPassesViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, passbook

I'm integrating a passbook system in my iOS app. I'm using the PassKit framework (Obviously ;) ). I'm using a custom tint color for all my navigation items. Is it possible to change the color of the 'Cancel' and 'Add' button? (From te PKAddPassesViewController) The blue looks horrible in my design.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can change the tintcolor. Since iOS 6 such viewControllers are based on [remote view controllers](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/10/remote-view-controllers-in-ios-6/), meaning their view is completely owned by another process and inaccessible programatically.

This can be confirmed by looking at the recursive description of the controller's view:

```
<UIView: 0x140b0780; frame = (0 0; 320 568); layer = <CALayer: 0x140b0860>>
|    | <_UISizeTrackingView: 0xe3b7300; frame = (0 20; 320 548); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xe3b7410>>
|    |    | <_UIRemoteView: 0xe3b9b80; frame = (0 0; 320 568);
```

The `_UIRemoteView` indicates that the contents of the view is hosted in another process.

Edit:

Curiosly with `MFMailComposeViewController` it works. This viewController has an addressable navigationbarcontroller.

Comment: So how did you do it then? :). I can't change the navigationcontroller of the PKPassesViewController.. :)

Comment: I could not change it for the PKPassesViewController, because it has a other implementation than MFMailComposeViewController. PKPassesViewController has no NavigationController which is visible/accessable from code.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 9 the button color can be changed. Subclass the PKAddPassesViewController and set the window tintcolor in viewWillAppear and make sure to set it back back in viewWillDisappear. Then use your subclass instead of PKAddPassesViewController:

MyPKAddPassesViewController.h:

```
#import <PassKit/PassKit.h>

@interface LHPKAddPassesViewController : PKAddPassesViewController

@end
```

MyPKAddPassesViewController.m:

```
#import "LHPKAddPassesViewController.h"

@implementation LHPKAddPassesViewController

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    ((UIWindow *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow).tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    ((UIWindow *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow).tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

There a simple way to do this in iOS 9. In the caller of `PKAddPassesViewController` use this:

```
PKAddPassesViewController *addToPassbookController = init...

[addToPassbookController.view setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: This doesn't work on iOS 11 (I haven't tried earlier versions).

Answer (score 0):

In Storyboard, Select navigationbar of your UINavigationController and then select the tint color

[image]

Hope this will help for you

Comment: Cant seem to find this? I change the colors programmatically. But this does'nt work:  [addController.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[GColor orangeAccentColor]];
        [self presentViewController:addController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];

Comment: Do you have uiNavigationContoller in your StoryBoard?

Comment: yes, i even have three ;). But i don't know if the bar on top (of the pkaddpassesviewcontroller is called navigation bar. It's not a push segue, but a modal transition.